# Does PyCharm Have Spyder's Variable Explorer Functions (mainly "Save As" and "Import")?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, spyder

I started playing around with PyCharm today, and it seems like this is the Python IDE I want to start working with in the near future.

Currently, I am using Spyder from Anaconda. What I really like about Spyder is that I am able to export and import variables from the Variable Explorer window.

This means that I can debug part of my script, save the results, and then import the variables back into Spyder at another time. I can use such variables without even having to declare it in my script as Spyder already assume that it exists from the Variable Explorer window.

This feature is extremely useful to me, and I cannot tell if PyCharm has this feature.

I searched many places, and I could not find anything.

Does anyone know how to get this feature to work in PyCharm if it exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm added some functionality similar to Spyder's Variable Explorer some months ago, as can be seen in [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/11/third-pycharm-4-eap-numpy-array-viewer-ipython-notebook-improvements-and-more/).

However, as far as I know, it doesn't have the ability to import/export the variables present in its Python console.

Comment: I face the same problem as @stungkit do i tried to use pycharm variable explorer but it is not as user friendly as spyder. But clearly spyder lacks features like addons and other stuffs for a full stack development.
So is there any IDLE which have a good variable explorer and options like Pycharm. I know this is greedy but that would be awesome . or any way to plugin the spyder variable explorer with PyCharm ;P , that would make my life easy